# 'Publishing to tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost...' has encountered an error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

So I set up a Tomcat server in Eclipse. I managed to get it running after quite a few hiccups. I then created a simple web application (just an index.html that displays a message. The project name is FirstApp). When I tried running it on the server, this is what I get -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you dont have the permission to write new files in tomcat installation 
directory , fix that. run eclipse with admin priviledges. error is coming when 
trying to create a new diretory in installation path

Comment: Can you help out with that? Like a step by step way to do it..?

Comment: do not use sudo command try using gksu eclipse, then enter your password.

Comment: I've tried using the methods as suggested by http://askubuntu.com/questions/249098/how-do-i-run-eclipse-as-sudo
but it didnt work

Comment: gksu asks for password but doesn't do anything. The password is correct, but it simply returns to terminal